# Angular2 refresh API every x minutes to watch change in response

Tags: ajax, rest, angular, refresh, angular2-http

Is there a way, in Angular 2, to watch for change in API.

Here is my case:

- I push a document to an API /document/upload
- This API return a DOC id
- Using a call to /document/DOC_ID, the API returns a JSON in this format:

> ```
> "errorCode":0,
>
> "docId":"585846a1afe8ad12e46a4e60",
>
> "status":0
> ```

Status can be:

- 0 = pending
- 1 = signed
- 2 = validated

This status will be "changed" by a worker on the remote server which validate the file. This state is only "interrogated" through the API.

On my front-end, I've a component dedicated to display the state of my document:

```
<p>Current State: {fileState}</p>
```

On my component, **how can i watch the change of status in the api call result** : how can I place for example a call which will call the API every x minutes to verify the state and update the view accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
checkStatus(minutes: number, docID: string) {
  Observable.interval(minutes * 60 * 1000)
    .switchMap(() => this.http.get(`/documents/${docID}`)
      // handle http errors here to prevent
      // breaking of interval observable
      .catch(error => Observable.of(error))
      .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.fileState = 
        data.state === 0 ? 'pending' : 
        data.state === 1 : 'signed' : 'validated';
    })
}
```

Don't forget to import observable operators:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```